# Как сформировать JSON-запрос для API Яндекс.Карт?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, yandex-maps-api

Реализую карту с собственными метками на Yandex API.
Цель — выводить множество меток по координатам из базы данных.

Использую метод, описанный в официальной документации Яндекса
([Оптимальное добавление множества меток](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager)).

Не пойму, собственно, как реализовать передачу массива меток скрипту.
Массив меток хранится в файле data.json,
но мне необходимо использовать данные из базы данных.

Подскажите, что для этого необходимо сделать? Вообще не пойму как завернуть код.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 32
        });

    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Примеры. Добавление на карту большо числа объектов</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- Если вы используете API локально, то в URL ресурса необходимо указывать протокол в стандартном виде (http://...)-->
    <script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//yandex.st/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="object_manager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужно ничего передавать скрипту, необходимо ему лишь указать локальный файл с координатами.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.json"          //вот тут надо указать ваш файл с координатами   
}).done(function(data) {
    objectManager.add(data);
});
```

Важно что бы ваш json файл соответствовал требуемому формату, представленному в песочнице.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна", "clusterCaption": "Еще одна метка", "hintContent": "Текст подсказки"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна", "clusterCaption": "Еще одна метка", "hintContent": "Текст подсказки"}},
...
]
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый Владимир! Спасибо за попытку, но это ответ на другой вопрос! Вопрос же, заданный автором, нужно уточнить: как при помощи серверного языка (например PHP) сформировать на отдельной странице динамический вывод данных в формате json. Этот нужно для того, чтобы всегда обеспечивался вывод актуальных данных из БД с учетом добавленных и измененных записей в таблицах БД - меняются телефоны, адреса, и т.д. и т. п.